# Flutter TextField Phone Numbers Suggestions?

Tags: flutter, textinput

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  enableSuggestions: true,
),
```

this doesnt show phone numbers suggestions on keyboards, tried different keybaords on android, verified it has access to contacts, also doesn't work on ios.
Should this even work? If not, where can I find that it says it's not expected behavior.

Comment: Have you tried it on physical device?

Comment: yes, on multiple, also android and ios

Comment: Same behaviour on my device. If i remember correctly, this issue was on Android for some devices. Don't know for sure, but it could be, that we both have devices, with similar bug.

Answer (score 6):

You should set `autofillHints`

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  autofillHints: [
    AutofillHints.telephoneNumber,
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout: [sms_autofill 1.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill)

**Use**:

```
PhoneFieldHint();
```

PhoneFieldHint is a widget that will allow you ask for system phone number and autofill the widget if a phone is choosen by the user.

[image]

**Only work for android**

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way I could find is that
install : https://pub.dev/packages/sms_autofill

and use below code

```
String? selectedPhoneNumber = await SmsAutoFill().hint;
log(selectedPhoneNumber.toString());
```